# Set alternating onClickListener to Recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have 50 recyclerview items which are green in color now when i click on item 
It turns to red , when i will click again then it turns back  to green below is code how implemented it

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
        ((ItemViewHolder)holder).Title.setText(position+1+"");
        ((ItemViewHolder)holder).imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (status==0){
                    status=1;
                    ((ItemViewHolder) holder).imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_social_person);//red icon
                }else {
                    status=0;
                    ((ItemViewHolder) holder).imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_social_person_green);//green icon
                }

            }
        });


    } else {
        ((progressHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }


}
```

now problem is when i click on 1 st item it turns red icon but when i click on 2nd it doses not changes to red icon when i will click again  second time it changes  to red icon how to solve this

Comment: Where do you store status?

Comment: at the start of class it can be accessed from all over class and with default value 0 @tinysunlight

Comment: So when you click 1st. Status change to 1.When you click 2st, it change to green beacause status == 1.

Comment: ok  i get it so how i can implement it that on clicking  1st item it changes to red but when i click on 2nd item i want to change it to red @tinysunlight

Comment: I add a ansewer .You can have a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tinysunlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public SparseBooleanArray array = new SparseBooleanArray();
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
            ((ItemViewHolder)holder).Title.setText(position+1+"");
            ((ItemViewHolder)holder).imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean status = array.get(position);
                    if (!status){
                        array.put(position,!status);
                        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_social_person);//red icon
                    }else {
                        array.put(position,!status);
                        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_social_person_green);//green icon
                    }

                }
            });


        } else {
            ((progressHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }


    }
```